# Make div use height from highest child

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have a number of divs of varying height, and I want to display them one at a time (hiding the others with `visibility: hidden`), but at the same time make sure that the content below the div stays in place.

I have this small html snippet:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="big box" >Big</div>
      <div class="small box">Small</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this styling:

```
.container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.big {
  height: 100px;
  visibility: inherit;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.small {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

What I expect is something like this:

```
+------------+
| Small      |  <-- The text "Big" is hidden by the small
|            |      box because it is rendered behind it.
+------------+
|            |
|            |
+------------+---------+
| Footer               |
+----------------------+
```

I know that when I use `position: absolute`, it won't work because the `container` div can't get the proper height, but what then?

JSBIN here: http://jsbin.com/xakedogihi/7/edit?html,css,output

Comment: what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Most common, including IE11.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:flex` and `order` to swap the order of your divs:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
}

.box {
  order:1;
  width: 100px;
}

.big {
  order:2;
  height: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.small {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big box">Big</div>
  <div class="small box">Small</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

This should work in all modern browsers

**Update**

I think I get what you are after - both divs should sit on top of each other without using absolute positioning so the footer remains below the tallest content.

```css
.container {
  padding-left: 100px;
  /*width of inner boxes*/
  width: 0;
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.container .box {
  margin-left: -100px;
  /*minus amount of padding above*/
  width: 100px;
}
.container .big {
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
.container .small {
  float: right;
  background: green;
}
.footer {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et facilisis sapien</div>
  <div class="small box">Small</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Ok? I'm running a relatively new version of Chrome and it doesn't support flex-order....

Comment: Ah sorry, that should just be `order` - for some reason it `flex-order` works in all my browsers.  I have edited my answer to show the change

Comment: @mzedeler - see my update.  I have added a different solution that I think better meets your needs.  "Lorem ipsum" (or big) is behind small as in your diagram

Answer (score 1):

Change your html and css to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="big box" >
        <div class="small box">Small</div>
        Big
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="footer box">Footer</div>
  </body>
</html>


 .container {

}

.box {

  width: 100px;

}

.big {
  height: 100px;
  visibility: inherit;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.small {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: But then the small box is rendered below the big box. What I want is to have the big box rendered under the small box (their upper left corners must have the same position).

Comment: No, the code that i sent you does exactly what u asking for, the top let of the small box is at the same point of the big box. Have use the dev tolls to inspect the elements?

Comment: Here is my jsffiddle https://jsfiddle.net/acardoso/14syp0f1/ . Please let me know if that helped you?

Comment: Thanks. It's still not what I'm looking for - as you can see in my sketch, the text "Big" is hidden beneath the small box.

Answer (score 1):

If the heights of the box divs are hardcoded, as they are in this example, you can set the height of the container div explicitly. So the CSS for container would be:

```
.container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height:100px;
}
```

If the heights are dynamic, I would add some javascript that cycled through the boxes to find the tallest one and apply that as the height of the container. This (using jQuery) is not tested but it should be generally right:

```
var height = 0;
var container = $('.container');
container.find('.box').each(function(){
    if( $(this).height() > height ){
        height = $(this).height();
    }
});
container.height( height );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you cannot use absolute position in .box is that .container is statically positioned.
"absolute" positions in relation to the nearest *positioned* parent.

Unfortunately, if you position the .container, you take it out of the flow. So the .footer will then be placed as if .container wasn't there. The easiest fix is to position both .container and .footer:

```
.container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  postition: abolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.big {
  height: 100px;
  visibility: inherit;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  z-index: 10;
}

.small {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 20;
}

.footer {
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. It isn't elegant, but it works:

```
.container {}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.big {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
}

.small {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

It solves the actual problem I had, but not the one I suggested to solve. Sorry about the diversion!

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for if you consider this a hack?

Comment: And btw, at least 1 CSS solution is already given, doing exactly what you posted yourself, so -1 from me for doing like that

Comment: None of them use width: 0, but I've just tried it and actually this doesn't work. I've chosen an even uglier hack - I'll post it here when I'm confident that it actually works.

Comment: Pete's answer works perfect with the question asked. What do you mean by the width should be 0? ... If you set width to 0 in Pete's answer, it still works

Comment: Well using `order` isn't supported by IE11 which is required. What I'm doing in the answer above isn't using flex layout at all which makes it likely to work in IE10, although I haven't tested it.

But as I wrote earlier, even my own answer above didn't quite work. I came up with another solution that I'll post as soon as I am back on the job.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand? .. `order` works perfect in IE11 ... I just ran this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6emmxhs/1/) without any issues

Comment: Caniuse claims it isn't supported, but I can see that Microsoft says that IE11 supports it, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127303(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks for the help!